# C# - Индекс находился вне границ массива

Tags: c#

```
switch(Shabli)
{
    case 0:
        PhraseToRandomDistFL(MainForm.phrases[this.rnd.Next(0, MainForm.phrases.Length)]);
        break;
    case 1:
        PhraseToRandomDistFL(MainForm.phrases[MainForm.phrases.Length]);
        break;
}
```

MainForm.phrases - это текстовый документ в папке софта.
`MainForm.phrases = File.ReadAllLines("Shablons.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));`

Хочу сделать так чтобы брало текст не по рандому, а поочередно, а  мне выбывают ошибки, как сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// class member
private int currentLineIndex;

  ...
  MainForm.phrases = File.ReadAllLines("Shablons.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));
  currentLineIndex = 0;


  ...
  if (currentLineIndex < MainForm.phrases.Length)
    PhraseToRandomDistFL(MainForm.phrases[currentLineIndex++]);
```

Comment: Крч у меня текст с Shablons.txt идет рандомно , то есть берет с него рандомно  в одну функцию, а хочу чтобы было построчно.

Comment: @PwnMasterAlex У Вас русский - не родной язык?

Comment: Родной, а что??

Comment: Я просто не знаю как объяснить, ибо недавно начал разбираться в c#

Comment: Короче , у меня в софте "MainForm.phrases" читает текстовый документ "Shablons.txt" , и берет с этого документа текст и отправляет в вк через API рандомно, а мне надо чтобы построчно с текстового документа брало.

Comment: @PwnMasterAlex Медленно, по порядку, используя больше слов и кода. И без "крч" - Вы же не за школой со шпаной общаетесь.

Comment: Хорошо , извините. Я сейчас все попытаюсь объяснить.

Comment: Смотрите, у меня в текстовом файле Shablons имеются текста вот так

Comment: 1 enter 2 enter 3 , ну то есть построчно.

Comment: Софт берет рандомную строку с текстового документа , а я хочу чтобы шло поочередно тип начиная с 1 и до конца , не по рандому.

Comment: "PhraseToRandomDistFL(MainForm.phrases[MainForm.phrases.Length - 1]);" этот код берет самую последнюю строку с txt и отправляет, а мне нужно с начала до конца.

Comment: У меня ошибки на "if (Тут ошибка < MainForm.phrases.Length)
    PhraseToRandomDistFL(MainForm.phrases[И тут++]);" , ибо этот код в другом классе находится

Comment: @PwnMasterAlex Добавьте в вопрос Вашего кода, ссылка "править" - под вопросом.

Comment: Огромное спасибо , все отлично работает.

Comment: @PwnMasterAlex На здоровье. Успехов! Слева от ответа - знак "галочка".

Answer (score -1):

В PhraseToRandomDistFL такая же система

```
switch(Shabli)
        {
            case 0:
                this.rnd.Next(0, this.phrasesTargetsFL.Count);
                break;
            case 1:
                this.phrasesTargetsFL.Count;
                break;
        }
```

Первый работает, а второй нет.